# How to add constraint to existing table with knex

Tags: knex.js

I'm trying to add a constraint to an existing table using Knex migrations.
The database I'm using is Postgres.
I've tried the following:

```js
exports.up = function(knex) {
  return knex.schema.alterTable('users', table => {
    table.check(
      '?? <> \'deleted\' AND ?? IS NOT NULL',
      ['status', 'email'],
      'users_email_is_not_null'
    );
};
```

I keep getting the following error:

```
error: alter table "users" add constraint users_email_is_not_null check($1$2 <> \'deleted\' AND $3$4 IS NOT NULL) - syntax error at or near "$2"
```

I've tried to add the same constraint when **creating** a table and it works.
Doesn't Knex support this action?

Answer (score -1):

i find it much easier to write raw checks in knex

```
export async function up(knex: Knex): Promise<void> {
   return knex.raw(`
       ALTER TABLE users 
       ADD CONSTRAINT "users_email_is_not_null" 
       CHECK (
           status != 'deleted'
           AND email IS NOT NULL
       )
   `)
}

export async function down(knex: Knex): Promise<void> {
   return  knex.raw(`
      ALTER TABLE "users" 
      DROP CONSTRAINT IF EXISTS "users_email_is_not_null"
   `)
}
```